# tmux で ctrl キーの代わりに caps lock キーを割り当てたい

Tags: tmux, key-mapping

[tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) で `ctrl` キーの代わりに `caps lock` キーを割り当てたいのですがやり方が分かりません。
(`ctrl + b` と押す代わりに、 `caps lock + b` と押してtmuxのファンクション切替を行いたい為)

環境は tmux 2.0, OSはCentOS6.7です。
tmuxはソースからビルドしたものを使っています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

出来ないはずです。
tmux は自身も仮想ターミナルですがターミナルで動くプログラムでもあります。
ターミナル上のプログラムではキーの押下イベントなどはハードウェアから直接取得せず、terminfo などを通して互換性のある形でターミナルから受けとります。
結果、修飾キーとして使えるキーや、それに修飾されるキーの組み合わせが限られています。
Altキーによる修飾を扱うのにも苦労する状態ですので、caps lockに別の機能を割りあてるような事は出来ません。

より下のレイヤー（X やコンソール）でなんとかするしかありません。
Ctrlキーが押しづらいのでしたら、CapsLockキーと入れ替えてはどうでしょう。結構一般的なカスタマイズです。